# show string in a desire format

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I want to show my string in a special format.
For example I have a string like this `s = "00012345";` and want to show it in this format `000(123-45)`

I use this code for it:

```
label1.text = string.format("{0,###(###-##)}",s);
```

But just see this for result: *00012345*.

What string formatting should I be using?

Comment: What is your pattern exactly? You wanna close with `()` where your non-zero digits and and put `-` after three digit or something? What about non-numeric characters? I didn't understand clearly.

Comment: @Soner: It's an example. I want to know how can I show my string to a special format. for example like this : `(0001) 23-45`

Comment: You cannot use `string.Format` to format another string. In this case you could consider parsing your string to an int like this: `string.Format("{0:000(000-00)}", int.Parse("00012345"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned you can't format an already existing string. First you need to convert the string to an int:

```
int num = Int32.TryParse(s);
```

Then you can do the formatting whilst converting it back into a string:

```
label1.text = num.ToString("000(000-00)");
```

Comment: I used this also: but it result this: `00012345`

Comment: @EhsanDavoudi No, you're working with base types, no other libraries should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "00012345";
string s1 = s.Substring(0,3);
string s2 = s.Substring(3,3);
string s3 = s.Substring(6);
s = string.Format("{0}({1}-{2})", s1,s2,s3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I mean to use just `string.Format` and don't want to use `Substring`